# Moving directory in the google cloud platform to the root

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cp, mv, gsutil

I have a bucket on google cloud platform. All the files within a folder. I want to move all those files within the folder to the root i.e.:

currently:
/folder/[files and folders]

I want:
/[files and folders]

How can I do this using gsutil?

Answer (score 2):

You could use this command

`gsutil mv gs://bucket_name/folder_old gs://bucket_name/`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a clever way to do this quickly (read: with one gsutil command), but you could loop over a listing of the bucket contents and run a `gsutil mv` command for each entry, like the Bash example below:

```
$ # We have a lot of stuff in "folder1".
$ BUCKET=mybucket
$ gsutil ls gs://$BUCKET/**
gs://mybucket/folder1/subfolder/testfile.txt
gs://mybucket/folder1/testfile space.txt
gs://mybucket/folder1/testfile.txt
gs://mybucket/folder1/testfile2.txt

# Move it all to the root of the bucket!
# This approach accounts for spaces in object names.
$ FOLDERNAME="folder1"
$ gsutil ls "gs://$BUCKET/$FOLDERNAME/**" | while read objpath; do
    newpath="$(echo $objpath | sed "s#$FOLDERNAME/##")"
    gsutil mv "$objpath" "$newpath"
  done
[...]

# And verify the results:
$ gsutil ls gs://$BUCKET/**
gs://mybucket/subfolder/testfile.txt
gs://mybucket/testfile space.txt
gs://mybucket/testfile.txt
gs://mybucket/testfile2.txt
```

Note that performing sequential executions of gsutil, one for each mv operation, is pretty slow if you have a large number of objects. I found that when using this script, it took me 38 seconds to move 15 objects (so about ~2.5s per object).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the * wildcard to source path and it will upload all the files of the folder to the destination without creating the extra folder.

```
 gsutil -m mv gs://my-bucket/folder/* gs://my-bucket/
```

Comment: You missed the quote. It should be `gsutil -m mv 'gs://my-bucket/folder/*' gs://my-bucket/`

Comment: `CommandException: The mv command disallows naming source directories using wildcards`

Answer (score -5):

You can use a trick

```
gsutil -m mv gs://my-bucket/folder gs://my-bucket/folder/..
```

Comment: I just tried this trick and it created a new subdirectory called `../` and moved all my files in there...